# Barcode with text wrapping and on every page

Tags: header-footer, positioning, wrap, pst-barcode, barcodes

I am trying to get a dynamic `\psbarcode` barcode (it changes based on the page) to display in the top right corner of every single page and I would also like the text of the page to wrap around this. I am working with some nasty code and wondering what the best way of doing this is.

First I decided to put the barcode inside a header. This worked but `fancyhdr` complained about `\headheight` and ended up changing the next pages automatically and screwed up the formatting. Even though I am aware of the dangers of this incorrect `\headheight`, I actually wished `fancyhdr` wouldn't give me that warning. In the end though, I thought the header wouldn't be the best option because I want the text to wrap around it. Being in a header removes this possibility.

The code I had for the barcode and word wrapping was:

```
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)
\psbarcode{sample text \thepage}{width=1.5 height=1.5}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}
```

and

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{1.5in}\vspace{1.4in}\end{wrapfigure}
```

Then I decided to use `\put` and `\parbox` to put an image on every page, as if it were some overlay. This worked great but then I realized the `wrapfigure` code only works on the first page. I tried using the `everyshi` package to execute the `wrapfigure` code on every page but it has not worked. I saw some posts already on here about just word wrapping around one figure but it didn't seem to help me. I did see about using the `tikzpicture` package but I am not sure if that's what I need.

My ideal solution (for every page):

[image: ideal solution]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If it is in the header, I do not understand how you want the text wrap around it.
Here is solution without a fancyhdr warning.  Placing it automatically on every page with `wrapfig` is not easy. Placing it into the text margin may be possible.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{headheight=0.6in}%  > than the barcode!
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\fancyhf{}% clear all
\rhead{%
 \begin{pspicture}(0.5in,0.5in)% save the space
  \psbarcode{sample text \thepage}{width=0.5 height=0.5}{qrcode}%
\end{pspicture}}


\begin{document}

foo\newpage
\rhead{}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.65in}
 \begin{pspicture}(0.5in,0.5in)% save the space
  \psbarcode{sample text \thepage}{width=0.5 height=0.5}{qrcode}%
\end{pspicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Herbert for your help. I'm able to successfully implement that part. Sorry, I was not very clear at all when I talked about the headers. I want the text to go above and wrap around. So really it's not a header at all, but I tried doing it that way (a nasty implementation) because this would force the image to be where I want it and on every page, like a header is. [This image](http://i.imgur.com/0SFyT.png) is my ideal implementation. I edited my post to add this.

Comment: @fubukada: see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks. That is what I have. The problem is on the third page of your example (the 2nd page of the Lorem ipsum) there is no barcode anymore. I am generating this latex code from an unknown amount of text and each page must have a barcode.

Comment: As I already wrote, it is possible in the margin.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How would that help me? That's a one time thing. I need the barcode on every page.

Comment: @fubukada: So you want the barcode on *every* page in the header as well as on the first line and wrapped using (say) `wrapfigure`? The former is easy. The latter, not so much. However, as Herbert mentioned, putting the barcode in the margin is possible on every page and *not* having to wrap around it.

Comment: @Werner: No, I only want it once on every page. I don't care if it's in the header or not. I only started doing it that way because I thought it was the easiest way. Like my example image, it works fine, but on the second page the barcode is correct but the text does not wrap because `wrapfigure` is only applied to the first page. If only I could easily apply it to all pages (automatically).

Comment: I did it already in my example! Delete the `\rhead{}` after `\newpage` and it will be again on all other following pages

Comment: @Herbert: see my reply to Werner. Your example just has a barcode in a header for all pages, without text wrapping. It also has an extra barcode which does correctly wrap text around it but it's only on one page. I need it exactly like my image but on all pages. (of course there would be more text, I only cropped the image for size sake)