# How can I make a QR-code into a header?

Tags: overleaf

***Hello*** everybody.
How can I make a QR-code into header like this[image]?

Comment: That's a barcode instead of QR code... that having said maybe use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40857/barcode-with-text-wrapping-and-on-every-page as an example. Fancyhdr and pst-barcode?

Comment: @user202729 thank you so much.